# Is there a faster way to ignore dates and get specific times in a datetime series than a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Using Python 3.9 on mac with Pycharm. I have a .csv that contains two columns: dates/times as a string and a float:

```
                       time  Value
0       2021-12-01 20:00:00    166
1       2021-12-01 19:59:00    165
```

The granularity of the time is by the minute, **most** days (some days are skipped). What I would like to do is take a single value for each listed day at a specific time, for instance every day contained in the data at 5pm. That way instead of having hundreds of values per day, I would have:

```
                       time  Value
0       2021-12-02 17:00:00    166
1       2021-12-01 17:00:00    165
etc
```

The best I have come up with from reading about string/timeseries splitting is a for loop where the times are split and the index of 17:00:00 is used to form a new list

```
df = pd.read_csv('name')

datetime = df['time'].str.split()
temp_df = pd.DataFrame()
for _ in range(0, len(df)):
    if datetime[_][1] == '17:00:00':
        temp_df = temp_df.append(df.loc[[_]], ignore_index=True)
temp_df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(temp_df['time']) #make datetime for further computing
print(temp_df)

output:
...
                           time  Value
    175     2021-12-01 17:00:00    164
    1083    2021-11-30 17:00:00    165
    3313    2021-11-24 17:00:00    161
```

The other way would be to split it using `df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.date`, but it doesn't seem any less demanding than my current loop.

I've found sources on sorting/selecting dates/ranges (including [the Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html)), but none that allow you to maintain yet ignore the date while selecting for time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to discard data where the timestamp's hour is not 17:00:00 anyway, I think the most efficient solution is to *not parse to datetime upon import to df*, i.e. leave date/time as string. Then select the elements where hour is 5 pm, and parse only those to datetime.

A small `timeit` comparison shows that string comparison is about as good as comparing the `time` part of a datetime dtype column to a `time` object - however string comparison would save computations as you parse a lot less string to datetime in the first place.

```
from datetime import time
import pandas as pd

# make hourly data, ~100k elements
s_dt = pd.date_range('2010-01-01', '2020-12-31', freq='H').to_series()
s_str = s_dt.astype(str)

%timeit m = s_str.str.contains('17:00:00')
38.5 ms ± 1.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit m = s_str.str.split(' ').str[1] == '17:00:00'
94 ms ± 1.92 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit m = s_dt.dt.time == time(17, 0)
41.9 ms ± 391 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: All three (@sayv, and @tdy, and @MrFuppes) have solutions that are ~10x faster than my code! This breakdown of times and the notion of skipping the pre-sort datetime parse is very helpful in conceptualizing where the time is spent.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df[df.time.str.contains('17:00:00')]
```

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm! and per MyFuppe's answer, saves the most time (instead of pre-parsing to datetime.)

Answer (score 2):

> maintain yet ignore the date while selecting for time

After converting the times [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time)
```

1. Either use [`Series.dt.time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to compare against [`datetime.time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.time):

   ```
   from datetime import time
   temp_df = df[df.time.dt.time == time(17, 0)]
   ```
2. Or use [`Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to compare just the `%H:%M:%S` portion:

   ```
   temp_df = df[df.time.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S').eq('17:00:00')]
   ```

This is all done without a loop, using vectorized comparisons and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

You can also check against strings (like sayv's answer), but storing time data as actual `datetime` objects will make analysis easier in the long run.